# Window.open() opening tab in foreground in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, firefox, frontend

I am trying to use `window.open` to open a new tab in the background when user holds ctrl and clicks link. It works for chrome, the tab opens in the background but for Firefox it opens in the foreground (opens the new tab and also takes you to it). I know Firefox has a setting to take you to a new tab when you open it but I have those disabled [firefox settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQqUX.png).

This is my code, I have added this redirect function to the `onClick` of a link, I am returning false to make sure that the link href does not get triggered. I'm using a link instead of a button because I want right click to open a context menu with 'open link in new tab' option.

```js
  const redirect = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): boolean => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
      window.open(url);
    }
    return false
```

Comment: You can try and do `window.open(); window.focus()` but the thing is ad services abused pop ups and they got locked down. Things we used to be able to do with pop up windows was removed.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work